# PHP namespaced class within variable

Tags: php, namespaces

Can anyone explain why the below code causes a "Cannot find class" error? Instantiating the class with the fully qualified name works, but eliminates the advantage of the "use" statement.

```
<?php

namespace
{
    use Foo\Bar;

    new Bar;    // Works

    $class = 'Foo\Bar'; 

    new $class; // Works

    $class = 'Bar';

    new $class; // "Cannot find class" error
}

namespace Foo
{
    class Bar {}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Tested on both PHP 5.3.2 and 5.3.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I suppose it's actually a [feature](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php). And aliases won't help here, for the same reasons:

> Importing is performed at compile-time, and so does not affect dynamic
>   class, function or constant names. [...]

```
<?php 
use My\Full\Classname as Another, My\Full\NSname;

$obj = new Another; // instantiates object of class My\Full\Classname
$a = 'Another'; 
$obj = new $a;      // instantiates object of class Another 
?>
```

And yes, it sorts of defeats the purpose of `use` with dynamic classes.